# Can't read my highlighted searches

Tags: search, highlight

In this display, what does the "xxx" mean?

```
:hi Search
Search         xxx term=reverse ctermbg=11 guibg=Yellow
```

On my display (cygwin/xterm), Search displays as black on black.

If I do this, nothing changes

```
:hi Search term=NONE
```

Apparently, "Search" is not (no longer?) the correct syntax name for highlighted searches.

How can I see what colorscheme "default" selects?
In /usr/share/vim/*/colors, it's a complicated reference.

Comment: could also be IncSearch highlighting. The `xxx` shows you how that will be colored in your terminal. Might also be a terminal configuration issue.

Comment: "The xxx shows you how that will be colored in your terminal.": do you mean it has no syntactic purpose, it's just displayed as an illustration?

Comment: Yes @n952162; it's just a piece of example text.

Comment: And `Search` is the correct highlight group. `:hi Search term=NONE` only clears the `term` property, but not `ctermbg` or `guibg`; to fully clear it use `:hi clear Search`. Not sure why the background appears as black; I guess that's probably because of `ctermbg=11`? Try using a different number/colour there, maybe your terminal doesn't support the "bright" colours 9-15? You can also try with something like `printf '\x1b[48;5;11m yellow bg \x1b[0m\n'` to check it shows up correctly in your terminal. Also check the `t_Co` setting in Vim; what's that set to?

Comment: The printf command printed out " yellow bg ", black fg, yellow bg, as expected.

Comment: As to ":set t_Co" the result is:   t_Co=256.  ":hi clear Search" did that.  BUT!  Setting ctermbg=yellow (or Yellow) doesn't get set!!! ":hi Search ctermbg=yellow                                    "  It's still "Search         xxx term=reverse ctermbg=11 guibg=Yellow"

Comment: I'm thinking now, it may be a cygwin bug

Comment: check your $TERM configuration. Also check whether t_CO=256 is actually correct for cygwin

Comment: Besides `Search`, check also the `IncSearch` highlight group (this was mentioned above;  I'm repeating it again in case it got missed).

Comment: No incsearch for me (I.e. :set noincsearch in my .vimrc).  I generally need to see what I'm searching for before it's all typed in).  But there's no change when I do ":hi clear incSearch"

Comment: $ echo $TERM
xterm-direct

Comment: Ok, Progress.  @MartinTournoij pointed the way ... all ctermbg >= 8 result in a black background.  And "yellow", too.  Amazing that I'm the only one on the planet dealing with this stock cygwin issue.

Comment: OH!  An @ChristianBrabandt hit it right on the money.  When I set t_Co to 8, everything is in perfect order!!   Thanks folks!

Comment: BUT!  This in my .vimrc has no effect!  It only works when I type it in manually: ":set t_Co=8"

Comment: Okay, the last update (hopefully) ... I still don't understand why I can't set t_Co from my .vimrc, but I've finally discovered that TERM should be xterm-26color - hopefully that setting in my .profile will be respected.

Answer (score 4):

`xxx` is supposed to be the preview of your current highlight settings:
[image: cyano highlight background]

So when i do: `:highlight Search ctermbg=yellow`, i get:

[image: yellow highlight background]

Even though this does not help you with your Problem, i hope it explanes the purpose of xxx.

Best regards

Comment: :-) ;-(
yeah, thank you, now I can stop searching for the hidden keyword solution to my highlighting problem ... ;-)

Comment: @n952162 Please accept this answer (by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer).